# How to set border around Twitter Bootstrap Icon?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, icons, twitter-bootstrap, border

1. How do you set a border around a T-bootstrap icon? The css border property creates a square and doesn't trace the icon.
2. What is the best way to change the color of the icon if the action's already been done in Rails? For example, I have a star icon for "bookmark," and it's light grey(although I want it to be white with black border) normally, and turns orange with the :hover css property. If I want to make the icon permanently orange if the user has already bookmarked it, would I use css or ruby to determine the color?

Comment: The bootstrap icons are a square image, you can't trace a border around that unless you create a new set of icons. And as for your second point, you will have to once again create your custom icons with the colors you want, you can't color them with just css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1. CSS does not povide shadows or outlines for image pixell, only boxes (thus box-shadow).

Preprocess icon images on the server side using a script + some image library.

1. CSS is the best way to change item colors. Just add a custom icon class, like icon-orange, and then use this CSS icon class instead of standard one.

(Again, preprocessing icons to yellow versions most likely needed).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by preprocessing? So do I just have one image that is already traced around & border-applied, and then am I calling that, or am I tracing it every time I want to load the icon?

And for 2, I would use Ruby in the view to determine which icon class would be applied?